# in R, read special columns with read.csv.sql

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I am trying to read a big csv file. Indeed, I want select a subset using a special column which name is Race Color.  Reading the file via read.csv, I have the head

```
library(sqldf)
df <-  read.csv(file = 'df.txt', header = T, sep = ";")
head(df)

id  Region  Race Color  .... 
 1       1          1
 2       1          1
 3       2          1
 4       3          2
 5       4          1
 6       4          1
```

I would like to use read.csv.sql for selecting a subset of df without use the read.csv file. For example, I want all the people with  Race Color equal to 1.
Using read.csv.sql, I have something like

```
>df <- read.csv.sql("df.txt", sql = "select * from file where Race Color = 1", sep=";", header=T, eol="\n")
```

but I have the following error

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
error in statement: near "Color": syntax error
```

Trying

```
>df <- read.csv.sql("df.txt", sql = "select * from file where 'Race Color' = 1", sep=";", header=T, eol="\n")
```

I have df with zero rows.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R automatically adds a `.` to column names with a space on reading in the data to make `Race.Color`, but a `.` has a special meaning in sql, so that will screw things up.

There is a built in method in `sqldf` using square brackets (`[Race.Color]`) to explicitly name columns we can use so that we don't run into that problem. You can also use escaped quotes : `\"Race.Color\"`

This should work:

```
library(sqldf)

read.csv.sql("test.csv", sql = "select * from file where [Race.Color] = 1", sep=";", header=T, eol="\n")
```